# Unable to make shared library while embedding Python to C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, fpic

I am trying to make a shared library which consists of one C header file and two C source files, one of which calls a Python file for implementation.
The compilation comand used is

> gcc -fPIC -c -I-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.4m -I/usr/local/include/python3.4m  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DDOUBLE_PRECISION *.c

I am able to compile all these without any error, but when I try to make a shared object file using the following command

> gcc *.o -L/usr/local/lib  -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic /usr/local/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m/libpython3.4m.a -shared -o libroughness.so

I get the following error which I am unable to resolve

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m/libpython3.4m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_PyObject_NextNotImplemented' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m/libpython3.4m.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am using -fPIC tag while compilation, however it still asks me to recompile with fPIC. Any help on how to resolve this case would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to build a shared library, then linking a shared-library version of libpython3.4m (i.e. libpython3.4m.so) is a better bet than linking a static library as you are currently trying to do.  Of course, you'll then also need that library to be available at run time.

Comment: But I am unable to find libpython3.4m.so anywhere, is there a procedure to build it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was able to follow on the comment posted and able to build a shared library, however my shared object file is unable to import my Python module. My problem is addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245188/shared-object-file-unable-to-import-python-module-in-an-embedded-python-applicat)